# Code::Blocks: How to run within IDE?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

When I ask CodeBlocks to run my built application it spawns a terminal window and runs the application within that window.  How do I instead get it to run within the IDE's log window?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that is not implemented in Code::Blocks as such.

Target executables are either run directly from the IDE (no console), or via the `consolerunner` program which calls whatever terminal is appropriate (e.g. cmd under Windows, xterm under Linux) and optionally prompts for a key once the process has exited. Which one it is (terminal or no terminal) depends on the "Type" field in the project's Properties window ("Build Targets" tab).

However, if you absolutely want, you can get the effect of running in the log window *indirectly* by executing your program as post-build step. In that case, your program's stdout and stderr will both be displayed in the build log tab.

Comment: I'm running scripts that output to the 'Build log' tab, but it doesn't respond to my input (eg `read -p "Press any key to continue... " -n1 -s`).  So I've resorted to using an external terminal window.  Is there something I need to do in my script or CB settings to get `stdin` from the 'Build log' tab? (CB 13.12)

Comment: @Nap: Redirecting the "build log" into a script's `stdin` is not something that is to my knowledge supported at all. Though of course all logging is done via a pluggable logger system, you could implement this relatively easily. Do note that stuff like "press any key to continue" with the build log isn't precisely a good idea (not only will it not work, but if it did work, it would be a desaster as the window would become unresponsive).

Comment: I think you've misunderstood.  In Eclipse, Xcode, and other IDE, they provide an integrated terminal window which can be used, not only for output, but input as well.  I'm running a pre-build script that asks me if I want to backup my files.  It would be nice if I could run this internally rather than using a separate terminal window.